# Are there any risks or drawbacks if i Import the same Pages library inside 2 site collections

Tags: 2013, powershell, administration, export, import

I have 2 farms which are of type sharepoint 2013 on-premises 2013 enterprise. and inside FarmA i have a wiki pages library which contain many wiki pages for policies and procedures for IT departments.

now i want to copy these wiki pages inside 2 site collection on the second Farm (FarmB).
now on FarmA i use this powershell script to export the wiki pages library:-

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity "http://FarmA/wiki/" -ItemUrl "Page" -Path "c:\1.cmp" -CompressionSize 1000 -IncludeVersions All -IncludeUserSecurity -Force –Verbose
```

and on FarmB i am planning to use this powershell scrip to import the wiki pages library inside 2 site collections:-

```
Import-SPWeb http://farmB/wiki1/**** –Path "c:\1.cmp" -IncludeUserSecurity –Verbose
Import-SPWeb http://farmB/wiki2/**** –Path "c:\1.cmp" -IncludeUserSecurity –Verbose
```

but my question is, if it is a supported operation to import the same list inside 2 site collections on FarmB?? I mean will there be any conflict on the columns GUIDS, list GUID , or conflict on other components? OR it is a supported operation to Import the same list multiple times inside the same Farm??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to import the list in the same farm multiple times as long as you are doing in in the different site collections.

Even if you are doing it in the same site collection, and if there are any conflicts with the GUID's the import process will stop with an error.

But whatever you try don't try it in the production environment. You may experience issues if the same user's profiles don't exist in both farms as you are using the include security option. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i am including `-IncludeUserSecurity` mainly to preserve the created & modified dates for the wiki pages, otherwise these dates will be equal to the date of Import...now in my case users do not exists inside the 2 farms (as they have 2 different AD), but the Import will assign these usernames to be equal to the service account which execute the Import process, and i am happy with this.. so there is not any real problem if i Import this on live environment... is this correct?  as the Import will replace these users with the service account which perform the Import